# Can Amps be used as a unit of measure for the amplitude of an EM wave?

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation, electric-current, units, radio

As far as I know the definition for the amplitude of a wave is the distance between the line $y=0$ and the peak of the wave which in most cases is going to be a unit of length. I also understand that for different waves, different units of measure can be used, for example the amplitude of a sound wave can be measured in decibels.

My question is, can the amplitude of an electromagnetic wave, in particular a radio wave be measured in amps? (This is what has been taught to me on a course but I am struggling to make the connection)

Comment: That definition is very limited. It may apply to waves on a string or in a spring but it is not general even for mechanic waves. For a sound wave in air for example, the amplitude is usually measured in units of pressure (above or below the equilibrium atmospheric pressure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  An EM wave fundamentally consists of electric and magnetic fields, which in SI units are measured in volts per meter (V/m) and tesla (T), respectively.   Customarily the peak value of the electric field $E_0$ is quoted as "the" amplitude of the wave, but the peak value of the magnetic field $B_0$ is related to $E_0$ quite simply:  $B_0 = E_0/c$, where $c$ is the speed of light in whatever medium the waves are travelling through.

It's true that if this wave is incident upon an antenna, the electric field would cause a current to flow through the antenna, and this *current* would be measured in amperes.  But the amount of current that flows would be dependent on the specific properties of the antenna;  a different antenna would experience a different amount of current when subjected to the same wave.

Comment: I suspect you can always specify the antenna, the same way you do to define other units. Unuseful and impractical, but possible

Comment: According to the same "logic" you can measure the temperature or your weight in volts (or maybe millimeters) . Or the light intensity in amps. Depending on what sensor you may use.